# Styling numbers in SPAN

Tags: html, css, frontend

I need help with the frontend. Is it possible to set the style for the number (string) without breaking it in HTML?

How I wish that it looked like in HTML:

```
 <div>Dodano: <span>127</span> stylizacji</div>
```

The effect that I want to get should look like this:
[link to Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9l2pblcbapy2nt/stack.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pseudoelement "after" and it works fine with any number of digits without breaking into html. You will need a background-image from the first answer.

```
span {
    background: transparent url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2722739/other/bg.png') 0 0 repeat-x;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 53px;
    letter-spacing: 21px;
    padding-left:8px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:-2px;
}
span:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:8px;
    height:66px;
    background:#fff;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Here is an example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6FaLd/17/)

Comment: sounds easy? this solution works **only** if the behind background is solid color, otherwise (if image or gradient ...) you will get a bad effect like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/6FaLd/19/ . Cutting off the last tail is very tricky and I think we don't have any clean solution (unless using script).

Comment: You are right, this solution works under certain circumstances. Hope it will work for the author.

Answer (score 2):

Here is completely CSS solution without changing your HTML. However, I did create a custom image for the background to go behind the numbers. You will have to tweak the size to make sense with your website.

Using a repeating background with a rectangle including a small space on the right-side to "space" out the digits. Use `letter-spacing` to give more space between the numbers.

```
background: transparent url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2722739/other/bg.png') 0 0 repeat-x;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 53px;
letter-spacing: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 8px;
text-align: justify;
width: 130px;
```

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/6FaLd/

Comment: Haha. I was doing the same thing [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c43P5/) but the problem is the `letter-spacing` sucks :) and what you did as a trick you gave this `span` a static `width` which prevents more than 3 digits.

Comment: In your solution known quantity of characters in this project is unfortunately not so well - it will be a contest for stylists...

Answer (score 1):

You can apply styling to the `span` element.

```
<div>Dodano: <span style="color:blue;">127</span> stylizacji</div>
```

Comment: I need a background like in the attached picture, every character has to have something like "border-right" without breaking the additional html tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div style="background-color:#f1f1f1; border:1px solid#dddddd; width:190px; padding:      27px;">
     Dodano:
     <span style="background-color:#152b53; color:#fff; padding:4px; font-weight:bold;">1</span>
     <span style="background-color:#152b53; color:#fff; padding:4px; font-weight:bold;">2</span>
     <span style="background-color:#152b53; color:#fff; padding:4px; font-weight:bold;">7</span> 
     stylizacji

   </div>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what _without breaking it in HTML_ means to you? ;)

Comment: Just what you showed, I wanted to avoid repeating backgrounds, but breaking each number on a separate element (SPAN).